# Is there a better way to compare two sorted arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift, comparison

In Swift, I have two arrays that I've sorted from largest to smallest, meaning the values of the arrays are `Comparable`. I want to define a custom way of comparing the two arrays to say that one is "less than" the other. An array with fewer elements is always less than a larger array. What I've come up with works just fine, but the `<` operator seems too bulky. It just feels like there should be some way to condense it, or that there's a built in function or a combination of built in functions that will accomplish what I want. Here's what I have:

```
func <<T where T: Comparable>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> Bool {
  if lhs.count < rhs.count {
    return true
  }

  for i in 0..<lhs.count {
    if lhs[i] > rhs[i] {
      return false
    }
  }

  return true
}

let first = [9, 8, 7, 6, 4]
let second = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
let third = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
let fourth = [9, 8, 7, 6]

let firstSecondComp: Bool = first < second   // true
let secondFirstComp: Bool = second < first   // false
let secondThirdComp: Bool = second < third   // false
let thirdSecondComp: Bool = third < second   // true
let firstThirdComp: Bool = first < third     // false
let thirdFirstComp: Bool = third < first     // true

let fourthFirstComp: Bool = fourth < first   // true
let fourthSecondComp: Bool = fourth < second // true
let fourthThirdComp: Bool = fourth < third   // true
```

Any way to improve the body of the comparison function?

## EDIT

Fixing the crash pointed out by Leo Dabus and including Martin R's answer:

```
func <<T where T: Comparable>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> Bool {
  if lhs.count < rhs.count {
    return true
  }
  else if lhs.count > rhs.count {
    return false
  }

  return !zip(lhs, rhs).contains { $0 > $1 }
}
```

Comment: note that if your first array has more elements than the second `lhs.count > rhs.count` it will crash your app

Comment: Good observation! Totally slipped past me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your comparison function can be written as

```
func <<T where T: Comparable>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> Bool {

    return lhs.count < rhs.count || !zip(lhs, rhs).contains { $0 > $1 }
}
```

Here `zip()` returns an enumeration of pairs from both
arrays, which is then checked whether one element from the first
array is larger than the corresponding element from the second array.

This gives the same result are your function for all your test cases.

As @Leo correctly noticed, your function would crash if the first
array has more elements than the second. With `zip()`, the
extra elements are ignored.

*Remark:* If the comparison should return false if the first array is longer
then you can write it as

```
return lhs.count <= rhs.count && (lhs.count < rhs.count || !zip(lhs, rhs).contains { $0 > $1 })
```

Comment: Very elegant - I was stuck looking at / for `indexOf` instead of thinking of `contains` :/

Comment: Super elegant! I got stuck using extra-long map filter bleh instead.

Comment: ZIP! I looked at `zip` but I couldn't make it work. And searching for how to "merge" arrays like this only yielded array concatenation examples. I was looking at `reduce` and `join`, but they didn't quite sound right. This is perfect.

Comment: This is where I learned it: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-408/?time=2295 :)

Comment: @MartinR: Wont both these evaluate to true? `[1, 2, 3] < [1, 2]` and `[1, 2] < [1, 2, 3]` (deleted my first identical comment by mistake when I was trying to edit it...)

Comment: @dfri: Those two evaluate properly now that I've added the `count` check properly.

Comment: @TimFuqua: Ah I only looked at Martins answer above. Note that with your addition, you wont need the left-most part `lhs.count < rhs.count` in your return statement.

Comment: Heh, yes, I just noticed that too. I was too focused on the `zip` portion.